# Make a long list into an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

Im looking a way I can take a list of about 700 items and assign them to a variable. I can use a for loop. 
For example:

```
for(int x = 1; x <= 649;x++)
{
  System.out.println("String item" + x + "=")
}
```

and then I would copy and paste the entire output into the code so it would make them all variables and I can use them for a project I am currently working on. The reason I want to do it this way is because I can use another for loop to translate it to code for something else.

Example:

```
for(int x = 1; x <= 649; x++)
{
  System.out.println("<img value ='" + item.get(x) + "'/>"
}
```

I know this seems a little convoluted but it makes sense with what I'm doing trust me. Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean "assign 700 items to A variable?"

Comment: I don't see a question here.. You have the code, it works as expected, your copy-paste feature can be assumed to work as well, so what is it that you want us to tell you?

Comment: Are you trying to making a program to print out 700 lines of code for you? -Also what is the question?

Comment: I need to assign each line of a list to a DIFFERENT variable. So like

Hello
My
Name
Is
Hypherius241

Would each need to go to item1 item2 item3 and item4

Comment: @user3109601 why not intead of printing out the lines you add them to a string.

Comment: @ns47731 I need them to be each assigned to different strings.

Comment: @user3109601 so like...an array of strings...`String[] myArray = new String[700]`

Comment: Why assign them to different variables at all, you have them in a list already, just access them from the list directly as needed?

Comment: Since Java source are just plain text, you should consider writing your output to a simple .java file that you can import to a project and compile. This would save you the hassle of copy and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Hello My Name Is Hypherius241";
    String[] arr = str.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("arr[%d] = \"%s\";\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
arr[0] = "Hello";
arr[1] = "My";
arr[2] = "Name";
arr[3] = "Is";
arr[4] = "Hypherius241";
```

Comment: This is great! I just finished fixing the txt file so it fit with this, but I dont really understand whats going on with this. Can you tell me how I might add ; at the end of each line and " around the strings >.>